# How to order the items downloaded by scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

So since it looks like Scrapy downloads images in a random order, I've been trying to find a way to sort images in either one of two ways:

1. Download in the order which the urls were scraped
2. Sort the
   files (perhaps by using meta data?) by the order which they came in
   the url list

I would like to do this in the most efficient way possible, but right now I can't figure out how to do it using either method. I looked into perhaps modifying the `Scheduler` but I don't think there are any options to change this.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that may or may not work depending on the page would be for you to parse the HTML using lxml and building your own tree structure for images. You traverse the HTML tree and find the levels of the images and build your own tree out of it. Pretend you have this page:

```
 |x|  |x|  |x|
 |x|  |x|  |x|
 |x|  |x|  |x|
```

where each x corresponds to an image. The structure of the parsed HTML document could be something like

```
<HTML>
     <Table>     
           <Column 1>
               Pic 1
               Pic 2
               Pic 3

           <Column 2>
               Pic 1
               Pic 2
               Pic 3

           <Column 3>
               Pic 1
               Pic 2
               Pic 3
    </Table>
</HTML>
```

If you walk through the tree created by lxml and assign depths to images and their parents, you can create this structure which can tell you the order of images:

```
Depth 1       Column 1          Column 2            Column 3
Depth 2 Pic       1                  1                   1               
Depth 3 Pic       2                  2                   2        
Depth 4 Pic       3                  3                   3
```

This is just an idea and probably won't work for webpages that aren't orderly and/or badly formatted.

---

I also had this issue. A quick work around is after a link is queued to be scraped (basically when the main function is called or when you return a request that goes deeper), you write the link to a file so that it will be sequential to the order you are scraping.

I'm sorry, at home right now so I don't have access to the machine with the code. So you have a function that is parse. I'm assuming you follow links.
I'll write some pseudocode

```
def parse(self,response):
    currentlink = response.url
    uniqueid = (a sequential number) #callerid refers to starting link

    with open("mylog.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(currentlink+"\t"+str(uniqueid)
    (whatever your logic for your start link)
    (logic for following links, something something callback="otherfn")
    (add uniqueid to your request.meta)
    return request


def otherfn(self,response):
     take current link, take the unique id you created in parse
     with open("mylog.txt","a") as f:
         f.write(picturelink+"\t"+str(uniqueid))
```

This is a rough outline, but there are many variations to this. I don't know if this is the optimal solution but it doesn't really take any run-time and assuming you're not going through a ton of images/links, will not take much space.

Having two keys to tell you the true order:

```
def parse(self,response):
    currentlink = response.url
    callerid = (a sequential number) #callerid refers to starting link
    sequentialid = 1

    with open("mylog.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(currentlink+"\t"+str(uniqueid)
    (whatever your logic for your start link)
    (logic for following links, assign each link you follow a sequential id that tells you the order of the request calls. callback="otherfn")
    (add callerid,sequentialid to your request.meta)
    return request


def otherfn(self,response):
     take current link, take the unique id you created in parse
     with open("mylog.txt","a") as f:
         f.write(picturelink \t %s \t %s %(uniqueid,sequentialid))
```

Comment: Could I please get some code? Not quite sure what you're saying.

Comment: A rough example. You can do a uniqueid that gets referred to through your other links (which will be processed sequentially). You could also opt to create a uniqueid as well as well as another number that tells you for sure the sequence of your visits. Adding that now..

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. Does this just write files that contain links which your images are supposed to be in? Or does it actually automatically sort the images themselves? Sorry, I don't quite understand what you're doing here without more detailed code.

Comment: No problem, it's very hard to explain and I'm pretty sure I'm doing a bad job. Essentially think of this as your process: You have the start_url link list. Each of these URLs are visited by the function process. As a result, you assign each starting URL a unique ID (1,2,3,...etc). When you go and scrape this site, you find images and start downloading them (via a callback to otherfn). In your callback request, you pass on your own uniqueID. When otherfn is running, it takes that uniqueID and stores it. Additionally it assigns another ID that corresponds to the image that you're scraping.

Comment: (cont) these numbers are sequential and you keep on storing them for each image you scrape. It also resets by the next starting URL. I attached a rough picture of what I mean

Comment: apparently I can't edit my comment, but here it is: https://imgur.com/LiqYNyf essentially, you can tell that 1,1 is the first image you got, 1,2 is the second.. etc..

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure if we're talking about the same problem here. I only have one `start_url` and my problem is that when I'm crawling through all the links or images on the page, I'm not returning the images in the order which the images appear in the HTML document if you were to traverse it from top to bottom.

Comment: Oh... My bad I completely misunderstood your question. This one is a lot trickier because you wouldn't know the format of the page. I don't have a solution that I think will solve your problem. I'll continue this in my original answer post. I might have a way that can work.